# The least distance of $f\in\ell_\infty(K,X)$ to $C_b(K,X)$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology

Let $K$ be a paracompact space and consider a bounded function $f:K\to\mathbb R$ not necessarily continuous, that is, $f\in\ell_\infty(K,\mathbb R)$. It's a well-known fact that the least distance of $f$ to some continuous $g:K\to \mathbb R$ is half of the maximum oscilation of $f$. More precisely, we define the oscilation of $f$ at $k$ by
$$
osc_f(k) = \inf_{U\in\mathcal V_k} \sup_{u,v\in U} |f(u)-f(v)|,
$$
where $\mathcal V_k$ is the set of open neighborhoods of $k$, and we have the following result, which is the Proposition 1.18.(ii) of the book *Geometric Nonlinear Functional Analysis*, by Y. Benyaminni and J. Lindenstrauss:

> Let $f:K\to\mathbb R$ and put $\delta =\|osc_f\|_\infty$, where $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ is the supremum norm. Then, there exists a continuous function $g:K\to\mathbb R$ such that
> $$
> \|f-g\|_\infty=\frac{\delta}{2},
> $$
> and this is the least distance of a continuous function from $f$.

This proposition is an application of Michael's Selection Theorem, which is valid for any selection with domain in a paracompact space and counter-domain in the set of non-empty closed convex subsets of a Banach space $E$. Recently, I've proved a generalization of the proposition above for functions with counterdomain in $\mathbb C$ (which I posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3724829/the-least-distance-of-f-in-ell-inftyk-mathbb-c-from-ck-mathbb-c/3734032#3734032)). Of course the measure of the oscilation changed, but we still get the least distance of $f$ to a continuous function.

I can see, by my proof, that it can be extended to Hilbert spaces in general, but, I wonder if this result can be extended to a much more general class, I would say the uniformly convex Banach space, or something close to that.

My question is if there exists a result analogous to the proposition for a more general class of Banach spaces, or if someone could guide me on an argument that could be valid to prove such a result.